# Get total number of rows selected or updated in bigquery with bq command

Tags: shell, google-bigquery, teradata

I am trying to migrate some TERADATA features to BigQuery and I've been looking for something similar to the `ACTIVITYCOUNT` in TERADATA since I'm working on shell script environment, here is an example :

```
SELECT username, password from USERS_TABLE where true 
. IF ACTIVITYCOUNT=0 THEN .QUIT 122;
```

and here is the new version I've did to transform the SQL query into BigQuery

```
    bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT username, password from USERS_TABLE where true" > output.txt
    ### How to get the number of rows selected ???
```

But I'm still struggling with the second instruction, I don't know if there is any native way to get the number of rows returned without doing a new sql query on the count cause I have a bunch of request to do the same thing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround solution:

**Select Statement:**

```
$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`' | expr `wc -l` - 4 | sed 's/-[0-9]*/0/'
```

**Update Statement:**

```
$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'UPDATE `project.dataset.table` SET sal = sal * 2 WHERE true' 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be various solutions, let me start with an easier one to see if it works for you.

(Harder one is to fetch results from a finished job)

```sql
ASSERT (SELECT COUNT(username) > 0 from USERS_TABLE where true) AS "USERS_TABLE cannot be empty";
```

Then your shell script only need to monitor if the query has an error or not.

See more on ASSERT: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/debugging-statements

===========

One step further, you can see that it may be not necessary to break statements into smaller pieces to be sent by shell script. You can write a SQL script which asserts in various places already with [Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery_scripting)